# Time complexity of this GetUniqueInt() method

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting

First of all, I know this is a horrible way of solving this problem. However, I'm not sure about the time complexity of this solution. I'm thinking this is O(N^2) because that's the closest I can think of. Basically, we loop N, and then we start filling in a list and loop that to check. Can anyone help clarify this?

```
int[] uniqueNums = new[] {4,1,1,3,4,5,5};
int getUniqueInt(int[] arr)
{
    List<int> items = new List<int>();
    List<int> uniqueItems = new List<int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
    {
        int currentNum = arr[i];
        if (items.Any(x => x == currentNum))
        {
            uniqueItems = uniqueItems.Where(x => x != currentNum).ToList();
            continue;
        }
        items.Add(currentNum);
        uniqueItems.Add(currentNum);
    }
    return uniqueItems[0];
}
Console.WriteLine(getUniqueInt(uniqueNums)); // 3
```

Comment: Yes, it's O(N^2) in common. You have a loop (O(N)), on every step you check items with `Any` method (it's O(N) too) and select with `Where` and `ToList` - it's O(N) too. So, it's O(N *(N+N)) -> O(2*N*N) -> O(N^2)

Comment: @Backs , any method is checking only for the particular i; why you are making it N times?? though i agree with you for loop. Can you clarify the second part as answer.

Comment: `Any` internal contains loop that checks all elements in the worst case

Comment: @Backs thank you for the help and clear explanation of how to figure this out step by step in the future!

Comment: Yes, it's a terrible way to do things. Check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=netframework-4.7.2 for a much more efficient method.

Comment: @JimMischel I don't think it is `Distinct`... The `uniqueItems.Where(x => x != currentNum)` will remove items that happen more than once - so my guess it is "first item with frequency = 1" like `arr.GroupBy(x=>x).First(g =>g.Count()==1).Key`.

Comment: @Backs one need to be a bit more careful as `items.Any` actually check 1...n items as length of it is at most `i` (which still leads to O(n) average as Sum(1..n) = n*(n+1)/2 ), but would make difference if outer loop would not go through all items (in some other code).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I think you're right. That code is even more confusing than I thought it was.

Comment: Absolute savage burns guys. I've done this in a white board interview, and only had 15 minutes to do it.